# Adding extra gas to a high velocity burner but the temperature in the vessel won't rise

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, gas, combustion

So I'm doing a refractory dryout of a vessel and I'm stuck at 350°C. Normally I would add some more gas to the burner and the temperature would go up, but now it just stays at the same level. I've tried to add some more air to the system, but it resulted in a temperature drop. I cannot reduce the air more than the initial setting because then the burner would jump in safe mode. This is the 3rd time I do this vessel so I know I can go higher. Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Is there a reaction or change of state taking place in whatever is in the vessel?

Comment: It's a refractory dry out. So the only change is that the water inside of the refractory concrete is  slowly being pushed out. The vessel self, is empty and is a closed box of 2,5x5x2,5m. The venthole is in the roof/wall and measures about 0,3x0,4m. The vessel does not have any internals and the burner is mounted in the roof blowing down. I've done some measurments and there are still traces of gas and CO in the flue gases so this also indicates that I need more air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess incomplete combustion. To check this add more gas and check the amount of flame that goes in exchaust, or try to ignite exchaust.

With incomplete combustion it doesnt help to add more air or gas. To solve it you need to improve mixing.

If you are using pressurised gas, it usually does air mixing in a venturi-like tube, any debree there can impede the mixing.

If you are using separate air input, you could try to make jets of air and gas collide, to mix better.

Comment: I've done some measurments and there are still traces of gas and CO in the flue gases so  I also would guess incomplete combustion. The gas input is pressurised around 100mBar. At the gas intake point of the burner, presurized air is added perpendicalur on the gas stream. this mixture is then pushed inside a cone section where it ignites. The burner is from the company globe heat **[link to burner](https://globeheat.co.uk/product/gas-burner-6-8-million-btu/)**

Comment: Fix it. It was indeed a problem with the air supply